# What is the difference between Linear regression classifier and linear regression to extract the confidential interval?

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am a beginner with machine learning.  I want to use time series linear regression to extract confidential interval of my dataset. I don't need to use the linear regression as a classifier. Firstly what is the difference between the two cases? Secondly in python, Is there different way to implement them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is the classifier will compute a probabilty about a label. The regression will compute a quantitative output.
Generally, classifier is used to compute a probability of label, and a regression is often use to compute a quantity. For instance if you want to compute the price of a flat considering some criterias you will use a regression, if you want to compute a label (luxurious, modest, ...) about the same flat considering some criterias you will use classifier.
But to use regressions in order to compute a threshold to seperate labels observed is a technic often used too. That is the case of linear SVM, which compute a boundary between labels. It is called decision boundary. Warning, the main drawback with linear is that is linear: it means the boundary will necessary be a straight line to separate labels. Sometimes it is good enough, sometimes it is not.
Logistic regression is an exception because it compute a probability actually. Its name is misleading.

For regression, when you want to compute a quantitative output, you can use a confidence interval to have an idea about the error. In a classification there is not confidence interval, even if you use linear SVM, it is non sensical. You can use the decision function but it is difficult to interpret in reality, or use the predicted probabilities and to check the number of time the label is wrong and compute a ratio of error. There are plethora ratios available considering your problematic, and it is buntly the subject of a whole book actually.

Anyway, if you're computing a time series, as far as I know your goal is to obtain a quantitative output, then you do not need a classifier as you said. And about extracting it depends totally of the object you used to compute it in python: meaning it depends of the available attributes of the object used. Then depends of the library too. So it would be very better, to answer to you, if you would indicate which libraries and objects you are using.

Comment: thank you very much for your explication and your help. I will put another question. I would be very grateful if you could help mes to choose the best tool for my data.

Comment: First, I am not experienced enough to give help to choose the best tool. I just can say if you're begginer, most of tutos and books about ML/AI use the scikit-learn library to make models. So that is why I would recommend this one. But if you have a limited memory or not enough one considering the size of your data, like many of us, you can use dask to make out-of-core for the exploration of the data and even to implement a matrix to compute in sk-learn object models. Warning, this is not the best, in my opinion the top is when you're PhD in maths (I am not) and are able to make own algo.

Comment: Then I do not mean at all you most drop it because you are not PhD in maths, I just mean it is an additional and very important skills to make the best algo corresponding the best fit to the data. You must remember the libraries provided are kits litterally, and that is your role to know how to implement the best parameters with these kits. That gives good models seriously, but I do not consider it is the best because a kit is "generalist" by itself.